# concurrent modification exception when trying to edit selected items of rich picklist

Tags: java

I have two rich picklists whose selected item section or destination values must be mutually exclusive. I did this piece of code:-

```
    LinkedHashMap<String,Boolean> includeRatePlans = getCampaign().getDataPackages();
    LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean> excludeRatePlans = getCampaign().getSmsPackage();
    for (String excludeRatePlan : excludeRatePlans.keySet()){
        if(excludeRatePlans.get(excludeRatePlan)){
            for (String includeRatePlan : includeRatePlans.keySet()){
                if (includeRatePlans.get(includeRatePlan))
                    if (includeRatePlan.equals(excludeRatePlan)){
                        getCampaign().getSmsPackage().remove(excludeRatePlan);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I am getting `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: Well yes, you're removing items from a collection while iterating over that collection. Either use the iterator directly, or build up a list of items to remove and then remove them all afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify the structure of a Map (i.e. adding or removing entries) while iterating over it with the enhanced for loop (and iterating over the `keySet()` makes no difference).

You can use an explicit iterator to remove entries :

```
LinkedHashMap<String,Boolean> includeRatePlans = getCampaign().getDataPackages();
LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean> excludeRatePlans = getCampaign().getSmsPackage();
Iterator<String> iter = excludeRatePlans.keySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String excludeRatePlan = iter.next();
    if(excludeRatePlans.get(excludeRatePlan)) {
        for (String includeRatePlan : includeRatePlans.keySet()){
            if (includeRatePlans.get(includeRatePlan))
                if (includeRatePlan.equals(excludeRatePlan)){
                    iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will work since `excludeRatePlans` refers to the same `Map` as `getCampaign().getSmsPackage()` and removing an element from the `KeySet` of the `Map` also removes the corresponding entry from the `Map`.